# Richtextbox Databinding issue on typing

Tags: c#, data-binding, richtextbox

After binding object to Richtextbox using bindingsource, if i type anything inside the textbox cursor will move to beginning. Can someone please help me.

I am binding as below

```
this.txtDescription.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingWard, "Description", 
                         false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

Comment: is there any **related events**? please mention about them if any.

Comment: There are no related events. Its a simple form in which Richtextbox is binded with Object using bindingsource. And after typing everytime I type cursor moves back to position 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the DataSourceUpdateMode to OnValidation:

```
this.txtDescription.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingWard, "Description", 
                     false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation);
```

If you want to keep the OnPropertyChanged setting, you can try changing the ControlUpdateMode, which is sort of a way to create a one-way binding:

```
Binding b = new Binding("Text", test, "Description", 
                        false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
b.ControlUpdateMode = ControlUpdateMode.Never;
this.txtDescription.DataBindings.Add(b);
```

Comment: It does works but the question is why its not working for OnPropertyChanged. For textbox its working fine only for Richtextbox its giving issue. Just want to know the crux of this issue.

Comment: @techknackblogs RTF is a different beast.  Changing the text re-writes the rich text format codes of the control.  It inevitably loses where the cursor was and resets it to the beginning.

Comment: @techknackblogs Alternatively, since you are just binding to text, it would seem you don't care about rich text formatting.  In that case, consider using just a TextBox with the Multiline property set to true.

Answer (score 3):

Setting `formattingEnabled=true` solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

try `richTextBox1.ScrollToEnd();` after binding

Comment: Can't find scrolltoend. Also problem is coming when I start typing inside the textbox. After typing anything cursor moves back to position 0. So I really doubt ScrollTo..will help